# Update Google Calendar from spreadsheet with script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update my Google calendar from events in a spreadsheet.

Below is my code, it runs with no error but nothing updates in my calendar and I have a cell in the row that contains the data that is being recorded as an event that should read "Yes" this is so that only new events are transferred to the calendar

```
function calUpdate() 
{

  var projects = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Spreadsheet that contains event information


  var workCalendar = CalendarApp.openByName("JC Work");
  //calendar that is being updated


  var estimates = projects.getSheetByName("Upcoming Estimates");
  //Sheet that contains event information

  var lastRow = projects.getLastRow();
  //get last row with data from estimates sheet


  var estRange = estimates.getRange(2,1,lastRow,4);
   //set range that contains data


  // process the data
  for (var i;i<=estRange.length;i++) 
  {
      if (estRange.getRange(i,4).getValue().toLowerCase()=="yes"){
      // do nothing
      }
      else {
        // each row contains (A)gc, (B)project name, (C)date and time in date time          number format
        var gc  = estRange.getValue(i,1);  // First column of row
        var project = estRange.getValue(i, 2);  // Second column of row
        var date = estRange.getValue(i,3); //Third column of row

    Browser.msgBox("New Estimate for " + gc , "Project: " + project + "; Bid Date and Time: " + date, Browser.Buttons.OK);
    //Test to see if information is correct

    workCalendar.createEvent("Estimate for: " + gc + project,
        new Date(date),
        new Date(date));
    estRange.getRange(i,4).setValue("Yes")
    //write data to calendar
    }
  }

}
```

Okay I made some changes to the code I think I had some errors, but its still not working.

```
function calUpdate() 
{

  var projects = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Spreadsheet that contains event information


  var workCalendar = CalendarApp.openByName("JC Work");
  //calendar that is being updated


  var estimates = projects.getSheetByName("Upcoming Estimates");
  //Sheet that contains event information

  var lastRow = projects.getLastRow();
  //get last row with data from estimates sheet


  var estRange = estimates.getRange(2,1,lastRow,4).getValues();
  //set range that contains data

//just makeing sure the data is being red correctly 
        var gc  = estRange[0][0];  // First column of row
        var project = estRange[0][1];  // Second column of row
        var date = estRange[0][2]; //Third column of row

        Browser.msgBox("New Estimate for " + gc , "Project: " + project + "; Bid Date and Time: " + date, Browser.Buttons.OK);  

 // process the data
  for (var i;i<=estRange.length;i++) 
  {
      if (estimates.getRange(i+1,4).getValue().toLowerCase()=="yes"){
      // do nothing
      }
      else {
        // each row contains (A)gc, (B)project name, (C)date and time in date time number format
        var gc  = estRange[i][0];  // First column of row
        var project = estRange[i][1];  // Second column of row
        var date = estRange[i][2]; //Third column of row

        Browser.msgBox("New Estimate for " + gc , "Project: " + project + "; Bid Date and Time: " + date, Browser.Buttons.OK);
        //Test to see if information is correct

        workCalendar.createEvent("Estimate for: " + gc + project,
            new Date(date),
            new Date(date));
        estimates.getRange(i+1,4).setValue("Yes")
        //write data to calendar
      }
  }


}
```

Comment: You are using the same value for start and end date... and what is this date value like?  Does it have an hour value?  So when should this event be created and how long should it be?  Please clarify. Also:  your title says 'update' but this is 'create' not update...

Comment: You are correct the start and end date are the same.  I am not sure how to handle the situation where this is an event on the calendar that has a time of day but not a length of time, if that makes sense. This is an 'update' to an existing calendar not creating a new calendar, I guess the title could have read "Create new event on calendar" but isn't that essentially the same thing as updating an existing calendar?

Comment: Forgot to mention the date value looks like this "1/23/2014 15:00:00"  which is the google spreadsheet number format for date time.

Comment: FYI in the message box the value from the 'date' cell looks like this "Thu Jan 23 2014 15:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)" @Sergie

Comment: Sorry, was away... Have you tried createAllDayEvent() which requires only a start time and shows up as a "whole day" event ? Otherwise try to add an hour for end Time and see if the event shows up. No time to test myself right now. Also what I meant by create and update was about events, not calendar... I probably misunderstood your words. sorry